# pls help me create a simple dataframe with row numbers in each column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I generate this dataframe on a much larger scale without typing in lists?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4,4]], \
     index=pd.date_range(start='2000-01-01',periods=5),columns=['a','b','c','d','e'])
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can do the numbers with something like `[[i]*5 for i in range(5)]`. Perhaps you should spend some more time learning core Python before tackling pandas.

Comment: @PM2Ring, would you like to make that the answer?  I'd give the same one, but I don't want to take it from you.

Comment: perhaps that was not a great question, but i appreciate the answer. i didn't have the [ ] on the i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.repeat` with `reshape` to get the final df you desire, this will be more efficient and less typing than your current solution:

```
In [17]:
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(np.repeat(np.arange(5),5)).reshape(5,-1), columns=list('abcde'), index=pd.date_range(start='2000-01-01',periods=5))
df

Out[17]:
            a  b  c  d  e
2000-01-01  0  0  0  0  0
2000-01-02  1  1  1  1  1
2000-01-03  2  2  2  2  2
2000-01-04  3  3  3  3  3
2000-01-05  4  4  4  4  4
```